# How does Eclipse run Tomcat Server? Switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make the switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ in my current project. I got some IntelliJ experience and my question is not about that itself.

When I run the server from Eclipse's Servers view, everything works fine. There is no special configuration, other than some timeouts and the deployed .war. But when I configure the Server in IntelliJ, it throws this message right at the start:

```
27-Sep-2022 16:21:08.899 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [XTomcat base dirX\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform]
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: XTomcat base dirX\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

And later some ClassDefNotFound exceptions, which I guess arise because Tomcat couldn't load correctly itself.

In the Eclipse console I see that it runs the Tomcat via javaw.exe, while IntelliJ uses the catalina.bat

Now I think that's where my problem is. But I couldn't find anything on how Eclipse runs Tomcat servers and already wasted 4 hours on trying to find that. Maybe anyone here knows.

Comment: I guess no one with IntelliJ expertise has jumped in. Check the tree in the Debug view for the node representing the javaw executable, and bring up its Properties from the context menu. It sounds like you have Tomcat for 32-bit Windows but the batch file is trying to run it with a 64-bit Java runtime.

Comment: @nitind Thank you, it looks like Eclipse ran it with a 32-Bit JRE somehow, altough it wasn't configured that way. As far as I found.
I downloaded Tomcat9 for 64-Bit and don't get that error anymore. Still won't deploy the .war I want. But that's for a different question.
My question still stands though. How does Eclipse run Tomcat?

Comment: Then I think you need to be a little more specific about what you're asking. You already have the info about the command line that was used.

Comment: Well, not really. I see in the Eclipse console that it was running the javaw.exe. But I have no idea of the arguments it used. javaw is just the runtime the Tomcat is running in. And therefore I'm missing the info what Eclipse actually did.

Comment: "Check the tree in the Debug view for the node representing the javaw executable, and bring up its Properties from the context menu."